# Wiener filtering; Matlab error: Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: matlab, filtering

I am trying to compute an algorithm in Matlab to wiener filter out an unknown point spread function given a noisy image convoluted with this point spread function and the original image without noise. I am fairly new to Matlab and I am trying to follow a code online so some things I do not understand fully yet so i appologise for any ignorance on my part.

I have the arrays:

NC2 = convoluted image with noise (599x599)

img = original image (300x300)

I have the following code:

```
for i=1:length(K)
H=fft2(img,599,599);
W=conj(H)./((abs(H).^2)+K(i));
G=fft2(NC2);
RW=W.*G;
RWfinal=uint8(ifft2(RW));
error=uint8(img)-RWfinal;
errorVect(i)=mean(error(:))^2;
end
```

I understand that RWfinal is a scalar structure so how do I apply the minus operation when this is in the struct format?

Comment: shouldn't it be `uint8` instead of `uint`?

Comment: Also, the first term in the subtraction is not a structure. If second is a structure, you may want to subtract a specific field of a structure from `uint(img)`. You can't subtract a struct and a non-struct. If you want to subtract two structures without accessing their individual fields, you can use `structfun`. You will have to give us further information to be able to tell anything more definitive.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be uint8... Been staring at a computer screen for hours maybe I should take a break! Thank you @Parag

Comment: what is your K in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint must be replaced with uint8
```